# Keep column names after using scikit-learn ColumnTransfer on pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am trying to write my preprocessing with SKLearn Pipelines and ColumnTransformer. However, the fact that the transformers return an array (and not a dataframe) is throwing me off a bit. I would like to be able to use the column names on the processed df also. Imagine the following data and pipeline:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), columns=list("ABCD"))
df["E"] = pd.Categorical(["test", "train", "test", "train", "test", "train"])
df["F"] = "foo"

num_columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
num_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
        ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ]
)
cat_columns = ['E', 'F']
cat_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps = [
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
        ('onhotencoder', OneHotEncoder())
    ]
)
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', num_transformer, num_columns),
        ('cat', cat_transformer, cat_columns)
    ]
)
```

Now I can get the transformed array

```
preprocessed_array = preprocessor.fit_transform(df)
```

and without the 'onhotencoder' step, I can even do something like this:

```
preprocessed_df = pd.DataFrame(preprocessed_array, columns=df.columns)
```

However, this is obviously not possible because the *'onehotencoder'* step added columns to the array.

There is also the *preprocessor.get_feature_names()* method that should in principle work, but it doesn't because some of the transformers like the *SimpleImputer* do not have this method.

Does anyone know of a solution for getting a dataframe back from transforming another df?

Comment: why don't you extend the `SimpleImputer` class to have a `get_feature_names` ?

Comment: Because it's not only SimpleImputer that doesn't have this method, it's all the scalers and the LabelEncoder, and basically any transformer that doesn't add new columns that is missing the method. and I think this is going down the path of reinventing the wheel ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to append set_output(transform = 'pandas'), like
`SimpleImputer().set_output(transform = 'pandas')`

Comment: This works, and it _uses_ the get feature names functionality mentioned in the Question. In the intervening years, that's been expanded to include all preprocessors.

Comment: (With a [probably also temporary) caveat for one-hot-encoder: feature names work, but pandas-output doesn't, if you keep `sparse=True`.)